# Bash command stdout

Tags: bash, shell, stdout

I'm trying to get a software version by using the bash script. The Command is simple:

```
/usr/local/sbin/keepalived -v
```

This is the output:

> Keepalived v2.0.13 (02/18,2019), git commit v2.0.12-53-ga9ed1993+
>
> Copyright(C) 2001-2019 Alexandre Cassen,
>
> Built with kernel headers for Linux 3.10.0 Running on Linux
>   3.10.0-957.5.1.el7.x86_64 #1 SMP Fri Feb 1 14:54:57 UTC 2019
>
> Config options:  NFTABLES LVS VRRP VRRP_AUTH OLD_CHKSUM_COMPAT
>   FIB_ROUTING SNMP_V3_FOR_V2 SNMP_VRRP SNMP_CHECKER SNMP_RFCV2
>   SNMP_RFCV3 FILE_LOGGING LOG_FILE_APPEND EINTR_CHECK
>
> System options:  PIPE2 SIGNALFD INOTIFY_INIT1 VSYSLOG EPOLL_CREATE1
>   IPV6_ADVANCED_API LIBNL3 RTA_ENCAP RTA_EXPIRES RTA_PREF FRA_TUN_ID
>   RTAX_CC_ALGO RTAX_QUICKACK FRA_OIFNAME IFA_FLAGS IP_MULTICAST_ALL
>   NET_LINUX_IF_H_COLLISION LIBIPTC_LINUX_NET_IF_H_COLLISION
>   LIBIPVS_NETLINK VRRP_VMAC CN_PROC SOCK_NONBLOCK SOCK_CLOEXEC O_PATH
>   GLOB_BRACE INET6_ADDR_GEN_MODE SO_MARK SCHED_RT SCHED_RESET_ON_FORK

From this output i need only the first row:

Keepalived v2.0.13 (02/18,2019), git commit v2.0.12-53-ga9ed1993+

I tried the following methods, but none of them works for me:

```
$ /usr/local/sbin/keepalived -v | head -n 1
$ echo "$(/usr/local/sbin/keepalived -v)" | head -n 1
```

In both cases, I'm receiving the full output instead of the first line only.

I tried to send stdout into file:

```
$ /usr/local/sbin/keepalived -v > /tmp/keepalived.txt
$ echo $(/usr/local/sbin/keepalived -v) > /tmp/keepalived.txt
$ /usr/local/sbin/keepalived -v | tee /tmp/keepalived.txt
```

But, I'm getting an empty file.

Can someone explain why is that happening and how can I get the first line only?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's happening because the output of **/usr/local/sbin/keepalived -v** is going to stderr instead of stdout.

You can redirect the output to stdout before extracting the data you want by doing `keepalived -v 2>&1 | head -n 1`